# How to make the tab bar fixed in the bottom when a content scrolls?

Tags: angular, ionic4

[image: Tab bar]I would like to make the tab bar fixed bottom when the content scrolls using ionic 4. It is working good till content scrolls but when I start scrolling , it moves with the content. Tried to use css , no luck.

```
<ion-content fullscreen>

  <ion-row *ngFor="let card of cards">
      <ion-col size="1" align-self-center style="padding: 0px 5px !important;">
        <ion-icon [name]="card.importance" size="large" [class]="card.importance"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="11">
        <ion-card >
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col align-self-center size="3" style="padding: 0px 5px !important;">
                <ion-icon (click)="changeColor()" [color]="red" class="star" icon-only [name]="card.icon"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="9" style="padding: 0px 5px !important; ">
              <ion-card-header>
                  <ion-card-subtitle>Destination</ion-card-subtitle>
                  <ion-card-title>{{ card.title }}</ion-card-title>
                </ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-content>
                  {{ card.description }}
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" >
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
          <ion-icon name="sunny"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>tab 1</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
          <ion-icon name="moon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>tab 2</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab4">
          <ion-icon name="moon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>tab 2</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab5">
          <ion-icon name="moon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>tab 2</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs> 
</ion-content>
```

I have tried this one too. But here tab bar is fixed but I cannot scroll the content . I think content also fixed.

```
  <ion-row *ngFor="let card of cards">
      <ion-col size="1" align-self-center style="padding: 0px 5px !important;">
        <ion-icon [name]="card.importance" size="large" [class]="card.importance"></ion-icon>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col size="11">
        <ion-card >
          <ion-row>
            <ion-col align-self-center size="3" style="padding: 0px 5px !important;">
                <ion-icon (click)="changeColor()" [color]="red" class="star" icon-only [name]="card.icon"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col size="9" style="padding: 0px 5px !important; ">
              <ion-card-header>
                  <ion-card-subtitle>Destination</ion-card-subtitle>
                  <ion-card-title>{{ card.title }}</ion-card-title>
                </ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-content>
                  {{ card.description }}
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-col>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-content>
 <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" >
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
          <ion-icon name="sunny"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>tab 1</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
          <ion-icon name="moon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>tab 2</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab4">
          <ion-icon name="moon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>tab 2</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
        <ion-tab-button tab="tab5">
          <ion-icon name="moon"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>tab 2</ion-label>
          </ion-tab-button>
      </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your tab bar fixed at bottom: for example

```
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
}
```

and put your scrollable content in a div just above this.

Comment: I could not do it with css. If I use the css, the tab bar has been unvisible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer to proceed with components rather using css-based solution. It needs some changes in your app architecture, but brings cleanness and maintainability (like you can later put more links and functionality in your app bar).
This way, you have to proceed somehow like this:

1. Put your  **app-root** selector in *index.html*.
2. Then put **app-header** selector and if needed, **app-footer** selector in *app.component.html*
3. Finally place header and footer codes in their own components. Here you can add a high z-index or any position property to header and footer view.

Of course you understand is the point is separating functionalities and views in a hierarchy structure.
You can read more [here](https://scotch.io/courses/build-your-first-angular-website/creating-an-angular-header-and-footer).

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the answer. I don't know whether it is a bug or something else, If I put paragraph and wrote something in it, then put the tab bar, it is working like a charm but without paragraph it is not working at all.

[image: Answer to the ionic tab bar]